# Problem with .exe file creation with pyinstaller, when I use an image button with wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, exe, pyinstaller

I built an algorithm that given a quote find a book. I've also created a GUI through the library `wxpython`. This GUI contain a button with an image on it. I have 2 problems:

1. When I create the *.exe* file through `pyinstaller` it shows the error for the button because it can't find the image (the image of the button), that I have in the same folder of the *.py* file. So when I launch the *.py* file the script work well but when I create the *.exe* file there is the error and the button disappears.
2. When I launch the *.exe* file there's the command window that is open in background. Can I avoid that?

here the code:

```
import wx
import requests

def FindBook(var):
    ...
    return ('Libro: ' + book + '\n' + 'Autore: ' + author)

class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Class used for creating frames other than the main one
    """

    def __init__(self, var2, title='Il tuo libro', parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title, size = (600,400))
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.var2 = var2
        my_sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        my_sizer2.AddStretchSpacer()
        libro = wx.StaticText(panel2, label = var2)
        font_libro = wx.Font(16, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        libro.SetFont(font_libro)
        my_sizer2.Add(libro, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        my_sizer2.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.Show()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        manual = wx.StaticText(panel, label='1) Inserisci la citazione --> ')
        font_manual = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual.SetFont(font_manual)
        hbox.Add(manual)
        manual2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='2) Clicca sul logo Bibliovago --> ')
        font_manual2 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual2.SetFont(font_manual2)
        hbox.Add(manual2)
        manual3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='3) Buona lettura')
        font_manual3 = wx.Font(10, wx.SCRIPT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        manual3.SetFont(font_manual3)
        hbox.Add(manual3)
        my_sizer.Add(hbox,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

        istr = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Inserisci una citazione')
        font_istr = wx.Font(14, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        istr.SetFont(font_istr)
        my_sizer.Add(istr, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        my_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)        

        logo_button = wx.Bitmap('LOGO.png')
        self.my_btn = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,logo_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SavePhrase, self.my_btn)
        my_sizer.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5) 


        panel.SetSizer(my_sizer)

        my_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()

    def SavePhrase(self, event):
        var = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        var2 = FindBook(var)

        frame = OtherFrame(var2=var2)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MyFrame(None, title='BiblioZam', size = (600,400))
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first problem with this:

```
import sys,os

fig_name = 'LOGO.png'

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

else:
    try:
        app_full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        application_path = os.path.dirname(app_full_path)

    except NameError:
        application_path = os.getcwd()


fig_full_path = os.path.join(application_path, fig_name)
```

And the second point using `--windowed` with `pyinstaller`